# Can we use in-app purchase in enterprise apps for iOS?

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase, in-house-distribution

Can we use in- App purchase in an iOS App distributed as a enterprise app? If not possible can we use paypal or any other purchasing mechanism for that?Does Apple create any problem here as they did for Kindle App using  payment other than their one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not going to publish the application in the AppStore, you can use any purchasing mechanism that you want.

Comment: Yes, you can use any purchasing mechanism you want... except StoreKit.

Answer (score 15):

Since the Enterprise license doesn't cover App Store integration, your bundle ID isn't registered and approved with Apple, this alone means the `StoreKit` can't approve any transactions because it's not aware of your application.

Even if this wasn't true, the infrastructure behind `StoreKit` isn't in place for Enterprise apps.

In any case you could argue that in-app purchase in an Enterprise application doesn't really make sense since you would be providing this application to employees, not customers.

Comment: That's why when I test the In-App purchase on our app with Enterprise provisioning profile, it does not work.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, if I can't use IAP with enterprise-signed apps how can I provide to my customer an app version which can be tested (even with sandbox accounts) before app store submission? Can Testflight be a solution? Distributing the application with testflight will IAP work?

Comment: @AndreaGorrieri You can use TestFlight to test purchases in Sandbox mode. For real purchases you can submit your app (and in-app products) for review with manual release. After the app has been accepted (but before release) you can test by generating app version and product promo codes - this will function exactly as any real purchase.

Answer (score 1):

This link shows all the types of accounts and what capabilities each of them allows: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH38-SW1

Apple Enterprise apps do not support In App Purchase, but they support a lot of other stuff