# What are my options when reached 100 device limit on iOS Developer Program

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

If a company is developing apps for different companies, then it is possible to exhaust the 100 test device limit for the normal "iOS Developer Program".

Currently we already used the 100 device limit and we cannot add more devices? The renewal for our account will occur after 7 months, and we cannot wait that long. Also take note  that the app that we are developing is using "storekit" for in-app purchases.

I suggested that we just create one developer account for each company/customer, but my managers think that it will be hard to maintain, specially if we need to maintain different "pem" files for each account to test APNS.

Are there any easy way to solve this problem? How do other companies solve this problem?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260791/how-do-large-ios-development-companies-manage-their-apple-developer-accounts

Comment: @JPetric the answer on that question is very interesting indeed, but I'm still unsure on how will "Each dev's certificate is added to the development profile" allow me to add more test devices. Could you please enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: Currently I'm just an Admin not a team agent. So should I purchase a personal 99$ account and add my certificate to the main team agent account and it will enable me to add more test devices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward:

Every customer should have their own developer account. It's not the developer company who is selling the app, it's the customer.

The accounts are not difficult to manage, every person will still have only 1 developer account, they will be only part of many teams.

As for testing, of course you will have more push notification certificates but since every application is supposed to have a separate certificate, I guess you are already managing that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In House are the solution to provide your client a testable version. More information here : https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: I have no experience on using an enterprise account, but I believe that it doesn't support "storekit" for in-app?

Comment: @Glenn - StoreKit is not supported, true. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12630192

Comment: Doesn't the license limit the enterprise account only for devices owned by the company? That means, you shouldn't distribute an app signed by an Enterprise certificate to customers.